# How do I make rounded corners on this box? (Blender 2.8 beta)

Tags: modeling

[image]

I drew in the kind of shape I want over the shape that I currently have. How can I soften the edge on this?

Comment: You can use the subdivide modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of solving this, but here is one.
It gives good control over the roundness of the corners.
Make sure you Apply Scale first so you wont get a strange behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Is this the right method for step 2 on the inside corners? Where do I find Apply Scale at? Is it a property of the "Bevel" function? https://i.imgur.com/ZWPHz1L.png

Comment: Apply scale with CTRL-A, 3. It applies any scaling done to the object to the mesh data it self and setting the object scale to 1 in all axis.
It's easiest to redo the inside to match the outside with a solidify modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Select the edges you want to round, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel. Turn up the segments for smoother shape.